# Justify text, but start text from right side to left

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to justify text, but that text starts from right side to left side, also last row of any text is not justify.

```
.text {
text-align: justify;
width: 400px;
}
```

Here is an example [of some text in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L4pzm/342/)

As you can see here text starts from left to right

Comment: making some sort of game, so i need that, it is rly odd haha, but thank you :)

Comment: @peter yea, that is what i want :) i mean i can write backwards, but to much work

Comment: The purposed solution is a little tricky and dangerous. Change read direction is not for layouts. Note than new browsers accept the property `text-align-last: right` and it aligns the last line to right, left or center if you want. More information in the comments : https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/wish-we-had-text-align-center-justified-as-an-available-option/

Comment: This is not same question as your linked question but ok, and thank you @Marcos Pérez Gude link helped me a lot :D